# Power Series Expansion Confusion

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to answer the problem, "Expand $(1-z)^{-m}$ in powers of z." There are some other questions on here about this problem, but they don't address my question. I understand that you can use the fact that 1/(1-z) = $\Sigma_0^{\infty} z^n$ for z $< \vert 1 \vert$.

But what about the case of z $>= \vert 1 \vert$? People in the other questions reference that no power series exists that converges in this case, but I don't understand why. After all, $1/(1-z)^{-m}$ still exists for any z $\neq$ 1 and m, and it is infinitely differentiable everywhere except z = 1.

Comment: An expansion centered around some other $z_0$ is being expanded in powers of $(z-z_0)$ not powers of $z$. But yes, you can expand this function around any point you want except $z=1$.

Comment: @Ian You mean that we need $z_0$ to be 0? That makes sense. But why can't there be some power series centered at 0 other than the geometric series that has a greater radius of convergence than 1?

Comment: Power series are unique. Also, once you hit a singularity anywhere on a circle centered at the point of expansion, the series cannot converge outside that circle. These are both basic (albeit somewhat surprising) facts in complex analysis.

Comment: Ok cool, I got the second one but I didn't realize they were always unique. Thank you!